# Increment attribute value (int) for each element using jquery

Tags: jquery, int, increment

i have an unknown number of section elements:

```
<section id="foo">
...
</section>

<section id="bar">
...
</section>
```

For each section which is present I need to add an attribute "data-serial" which is an integer starting at 0 and being incremented by 1 for each section present, for example the above would turn into:

```
<section id="foo" data-serial="0">
...
</section>

<section id="bar" data-serial="1">
...
</section>

<section id="bla" data-serial="2">
...
</section>
...
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var current = 0;
$("section").each(function() {
   $(this).data("serial", current);
   current++;
});
```

This loops through all `section` elements in the document, and attaches the value of `current` to each element using the jQuery `data` method.

Answer (score 12):

A modified version of James Allardice's answer taking advantage of the rarely used parameters that each passes to the function it is given. The first parameter is the index of the current iteration of the loop.

http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$("section").each(function(index) {
   $(this).attr("data-serial", index);
});
```

Comment: Everybody always forgets those poor little parameters. Nice to actually see a use for it for a change. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, the wonders of jQuery, making everything even easier than you think at first!

Comment: for some reason this doesnt work. it seems the index value is not set for the data-serial attribute

Comment: @maze: weird. I created a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/3FbWN/) and when I use firebug to examine the generated html the attributes are showing up... Though having just seen the accepted answer that isn't setting the data-serial attribute but updating an internal data element. I assume this is what you in fact wanted?

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
var i = 0;
$('section').each(function() {
    $(this).data('serial', i++);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("section").each(function(i, e) { $(e).attr("data-serial", i) });
```